# Heroku database performance experience needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, database-design, heroku

**We are experiencing some serious scaling challenges for our intelligent search engine/aggregator**. Our database holds around 200k objects. From profiling and newrelic it seems most of our troubles may come from the database. We are using the smallest dedicated database Heroku provide (Ronin).

**We have been looking into indexing and caching**. So far we managed to solve our problems by reducing database calls and caching content intelligently, but now even this seems to reach an end. We are constantly asking ourselves if our code/configuration is good enough or if we are simply not using enough "hardware".

We suspect that the database solution we buy from Heroku may be performing insufficiently. For example, just doing a simple count (no joins, no nothing) on the 200k items takes around 250ms. This seems like a *long* time, even though postgres is known for its bad performance on counts?

We have also started to use geolocation lookups based on latitude/longitude. Both columns are indexed floats. Doing a distance calculation involves pretty complicated math, but we are using the very well recommended `geocoder` gem that is suspected to run *very* optimized queries. Even geocoder still takes 4-10 seconds to perform a lookup on, say, 40.000 objects, returning only a limit of the first nearest 10. This again sounds like *a long time*, and all the experienced people we consult says that it sound very odd, again hinting at the database performance.

**So basically we wonder: What can we expect from the database? Might there be a problem?** And what can we expect if we decide to upgrade?

An additional question I have is: I read [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#performance) that we can improve performance by loading the entire database into memory. Are we supposed to configure this ourselves and if so how?

**UPDATE ON THE LAST QUESTION:**
I got this from the helpful people at Heroku support:

> "What this means is having enough memory (a large enough dedicated
>   database) to store your hot data set in memory. This isn't something
>   you have to do manually, Postgres is configured automatically use all
>   available memory on our dedicated databases.
>
> I took a look at your database and it looks like you're currently
>   using about 1.25 GB of RAM, so you haven't maxed your memory usage
>   yet."

**UPDATE ON THE NUMBERS AND FIGURES**

Okay so now I've had time to look into the numbers and figures, and I'll try to answer the questions below as follows:

- First of all, the db consists of around 29 tables with a lot of relations. But in reality most queries are done on a single table (some additional resources are joined in, to provide all needed information for the views).
- The table has 130 columns.
- Currently it holds around 200k records but only 70k are active - hence all indexes are made as partial-indexes on this "state".
- All columns we search are indexed correctly and none is of text-type, and many are just booleans.

**Answers to questions:**

1. Hmm the baseline performance it's kind of hard to tell, we have sooo many different selects. The time it takes varies typically from 90ms to 250ms selecting a limit of 20 rows. We have a LOT of counts on the same table all varying from 250ms to 800ms.
2. Hmm well, that's hard to say cause they wont give it a shot.
3. We have around 8-10 users/clients running requests at the same time.
4. Our query load: In new relic's database reports it says this about the last 24 hours: `throughput: 9.0 cpm, total time: 0.234 s, avg time: 25.9 ms`
5. Yes we have examined the query plans of our long-running queries. The count queries are especially slow, often over 500ms for a pretty simple count on the 70k records done on indexed columns with a result around 300

Comment: I've created a couple apps on Heroku, using the same exact configuration and code as my production app, that ended up being slow as hell for no apparent reason.  I would start simple and consider that it might just be on a bad machine.

Comment: So what hosting are you using instead? And do you have any comments directly on the postgres db performance?

Comment: Are you running the system on a staging environment also? If so does this run at the same slow speed? It might be worth comparing a staging and production environment that are identical to one another in order to check, for piece of mind, whether its the code or the host that is the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right - I'm running it on my local macbook pro (latest model) developer machine as well, and here it's almost the same speed - I would expect my production setup at the host to be way faster - right?

Comment: This is a key piece of info: When you run the app in another environment, you get similar performance. This is great news! You can probably set aside the idea that there is something wrong with Heroku, and focus your energy on tuning your app. Which queries need to be tuned? Can old data be purged? What parts of the app are good candidates for caching? Look at a single user's session, and identify which data could have been cached, then look at which data could be cached and shared across multiple users. (eg. certain parts of the app look the same for everyone, and can be cached)

Comment: 120 columns, most with booleans: are these nullable? Are they indexed? If they are nullable and mostly null, you could try to squeeze them out into an attribute-value kind of table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've tuned a few Rails apps hosted on Heroku, and also hosted on other platforms, and usually the problems fall into a few basic categories:

1. Doing too much in ruby that could be done at the db level (sorting, filtering, join data, etc)
2. Slow queries
3. Inefficient use of indexes (not enough, or too many)
4. Trying too hard to do it all in the db (this is not as common in rails, but does happen)
5. Not optimizing cacheable data
6. Not effectively using background processing

Right now its hard to help you because your question doesn't contain any specifics. I think you'll get a better response if you pinpoint the biggest issue you need help with and then ask.

Some info that will help us help you:

1. What is the average response time of your actions? (from new relic, request-log-analyzer, logs)
2. What is the slowest request that you want help with?
3. What are the queries and code in that request?
4. Is the site's performance different when you run it locally vs. heroku?

In the end I think you'll find that it is not an issue specific to Heroku, and if you had your app deployed on amazon, engineyard, etc you'd have the same performance. The good news is I think that your problems are common, and shouldn't be too hard to fix once you've done some benchmarking and profiling.

-John McCaffrey

Comment: I've learned a lot the last few months on this topic, and your answers are the most constructive ones, that comes closest to what I'v done and what worked for me. Thanks man, hope it will help someone else.

Comment: @J_McCaffrey This is a fantastic overview of things people should look into to gain a basic understanding of their program's behaviour. Great answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

> We are constantly asking...
>
> ...this seems a lot...
>
> ...that is suspected...
>
> ...What can we expect...

Good news! You can put and end to seeming, suspecting wondering and expecting through the magic of measurement!!!

Seriously though, you've not mentioned any of the basic points you'd need to get a useful answer:

1. What's the baseline performance of the DB running a sequential scan and single-row index fetches? You say Heroku say your DB fits in RAM, so you shouldn't see disk I/O issues when you measure.
2. Does this performance match whatver Heroku say it should be?
3. How many concurrent clients?
4. What's your query load - what queries and how often?
5. Have you checked the query plans for any of your suspiciously long-running queries?

Once you've got this sort of information, maybe someone can say something useful. As it stands anything you read here is just guesswork.

Comment: Well - true that is - and I think I can answer almost all your questions, cause I've been looking into most of them - just need a little time to dig out all the numbers - be right back :-)

Answer (score 1):

First: you should check your postgres configuration. (show all from within psql or another client, or just look at postgres.conf in the data directory) The parameter with the largest impact on performance is `effective_cache_size`, which should be set to about (total_physical_ram - memory_in_use_by_kernel_and_all_processes). For a 4GB machine, this often is around 3GB (4-1). (this is very course tuning, but will give the best results for a first step)

Second: *why* do you want all the counts? Better use a typical query: just ask for what is needed, not what is available. (reason: there is no possible optimisation for a COUNT(*): eiither the whole table, or a whole index needs to be scanned)

Third: start gathering and analysing some queryplans (for typical queries that perform badly). You can get a query plan by putting `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before the actual query. (another way is to increase the logging level, and obtain them from the logfile)  A bad queryplan can point you at missing statistics or indexes, or even at bad data-modelling.

Answer (score 0):

Newrelic monitoring can be included as an add-on for heroku (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic).  At the very least this should give you a lot of insight into what is happening behind the scenes, and may help you pinpoint some issues.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I have already integrated that, and it too, tells me that my app is not fast enough - but at the other hand, I don't know what to expect, so I'm very confused about the numbers - am I just supposed to crank up the (very) expensive volume (read db offerings), or am I going to do a lot more debugging/optimizing in my code (hard to see where I still can), or am I just stuck with a slow performing hosting facility?

Comment: Ah, missed that.  You're right that the performance is suspect. You can contact heroku support and ask them to look into this for you.  You can do `heroku pg:info` to see how large your database is, perhaps it is near the limit (5GB for the basic DB), which might cause some issues.